# Android determine orientation and screen size based on predefined values

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

What i want is ask a method and get an enum back that resolves to this:

Use Orientation Qualifiers
Some layouts work well in both landscape and portrait orientations, but most of them can benefit from adjustments. In the News Reader sample app, here is how the layout behaves in each screen size and orientation:

small screen, portrait

small screen, landscape

7" tablet, portrait

7" tablet, landscape

10" tablet, portrait

10" tablet, landscape

TV, landscape

-- http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseOriQuali

I have found different versions of detecting screen size and such but i would like this simple list turned into an enum that i could get back when asking a method.

Question is what these different sizes correlates to, based on screen size?

Example of what i want to do:

CurrentDevice cd = getDevicePreferences();

That would then yield, cd.Small_Screen_Portrait or cd.Tablet7_Landscape etc

**Update**

What i want to do is figure out if i should display more info on the screen since the device has a large screen. On my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 i would display 2 fragments and a menu but on my normal Samsung galaxy S i would only display a single fragment.

Comment: That list pertains to screen size and orientation. It has nothing to do with resolution.

Comment: Updated the question slightly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the wrong road. Try reading this first

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Usually you would want to define your xml layouts, thats the right way to handle multiple devices, nothing or little should be done in java code.